# ¿Por qué el resultado que sale no es el que espero?

Tags: python, lista

El problema consiste en que no obtengo el resultado esperado en este bucle, y no sé por qué, ni cómo arreglarlo. Ya de antemano sé que está incompleto y de seguro mal, pero me parece lógico de acuerdo a lo que tengo que hacer.

```py
def problemon(listaDeListas, indice, lista):

  for l in listaDeListas:
      dato=l[indice]
      p=funcionAux(dato, lista)
      l.pop(indice)
      l.insert(indice,p)
  return listaDeListas
```

`funcionAux` es una función ya definida, que con un número y una lista dadas, devuelve el índice del primer elemento mayor que el número en dicha lista.

Mi idea es reusar el método en el que estoy creando. De tal forma podría aplicarlo a una gran lista de listas, donde yéndome a la posición determinada por "indice" y con el resultado de `funcionAux` en la mano, podría ubicarlo en la posición original en la lista de listas.

En vez de devolver:

```py
problemon([1,10,100],[2,20,200],[3,30,300],[4,40,400],0,[2,4])
Salida: [[0, 10, 100], [1, 20, 200], [1, 30, 300], [2, 40, 400]]
```

Me tira:

```py
Salida: [[0, 0, 100], [0, 0, 200], [0, 1, 300], [1, 1, 400]]
```

Por no decir que ese valor varía. La primera vez que lo ejecuto me sale bien, pero si lo repito ya me sale lo que acabo de mostrar.

De todas formas, no creo que un solo bucle pueda meterla tantas cosas para hacer. Llevo ya varias horas sin saber cómo arreglarlo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sospecho que tengas el error dentro de `funcionAux()`, cuyo código no muestras.

La función `funcionAux()`, según la describes, ha de retonar el índice del primer elemento de una lista que sea mayor que un dato dado. Sin embargo no especificas qué ha de retornar si ninguno de los elementos de la lista es mayor que el dato dado. Posibles valores de retorno para este caso podrían ser `None` (que es un valor Python que representa "nada"), o bien `-1` si quieres usar un "estilo C" para señalar que ha ocurrido un error. De esta segunda forma la función siempre retorna un entero, pero el valor -1 señalaría que no se ha encontrado, pues no puede haber índices negativos.

Según el ejemplo que pones, en cambio, ante la llamada `funcionAux(4, [2,4])` parece que esperas que retorne 2. Esto no lo entiendo, pues ninguno de los elementos de la lista `[2,4]` es mayor de `4`. Sería uno de los casos antes descritos en los que podrías retornar `None` o `-1`. Parece que lo que retornas en este caso es un índice fuera de la lista, quizás el primer índice fuera de la lista (es decir, lo que sería en realidad `len(lista)`).

Una función que hace lo que pides, salvo por la parte en que no está claro qué hacer si no se encuentra el elemento mayor que el dato, sería la siguiente:

```
def funcionAux(dato, lista):
    caso_error = len(lista) # O bien None, o bien -1
    for i, n in enumerate(lista):
        if n > dato:
            return i
    # Si se agota el bucle sin haberlo hallado
    return caso_error
```

Usando esta función, junto con el resto de tu código, el resultado que sale coincide con el que tú querías que saliera:

```
def problemon(listaDeListas, indice, lista):
    for l in listaDeListas:
          dato=l[indice]
          p=funcionAux(dato, lista)
          l.pop(indice)
          l.insert(indice,p)
    return listaDeListas


s = problemon([[1,10,100],[2,20,200],[3,30,300],[4,40,400]], 0, [2,4])
print(s)
```

```
[[0, 10, 100], [1, 20, 200], [1, 30, 300], [2, 40, 400]]
```

Y todas las veces que ejecuto el programa (o si ejecuto la misma función con los mismos parámetros varias veces) obtengo de forma consistente el mismo resultado.

### Ampliación

Una posible razón por la que no te sale lo mismo la siguiente vez que lo ejecutas, es que estés pasando esta segunda vez el resultado de la anterior. Ya que tu función `problemon()` modifica la lista que recibe como parámetro *in-situ*, cuando la función ha terminado la lista ha cambiado, de modo que si haces algo como esto:

```
lista =[[1,10,100],[2,20,200],[3,30,300],[4,40,400]]
s = problemon(lista, 0, [2,4])
```

no solo tendrás en `s` el resultado `[[0, 10, 100], [1, 20, 200], [1, 30, 300], [2, 40, 400]]`, sino que eso mismo lo tendrás también en `lista`. Si seguidamente haces de nuevo `problemon(lista, 0, [2,4])` ya no le estarías pasando la misma lista que la primera vez, por lo que cambiará el resultado.

En general no es buena idea que una función que recibe una lista la modifique. Lo correcto sería que la función retorne una nueva lista con el resultado deseado, pero sin modificar la que recibió como parámetro.

Por ejemplo así:

```
def problemon(listaDeListas, indice, lista):
    resultado = []
    for l in listaDeListas:
        dato = l[indice]
        p = funcionAux(dato, lista)
        resultado.append(l[:indice] + [p] + l[indice+1:])
    return resultado
```

Comment: Perdona, con tantas cosas que comentar sobre el problema se me pasó. En caso de que no exisitiera el elemento en la lista, devuelve el índice siguiente de la lista. Por ejemplo, con x=10 y una lista=[2,4,8], retornaría 3.

Comment: @daenius Ok, eso es lo que supuse y así implementé `funcionAux()` en mi respuesta. Creo que tu problema pueda estar entonces en lo que explico en la parte "Ampliación"